# using AND operator with two select?

Tags: mysql

i was doing some tests about sql in my lab , so i try to make 2 select statements with AND operator :

```
mysql> select * from users where id = 1 and select * from users where id = 2;
```

and give me this error :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'select * from users where id = 2' at line 1

i search in web and solve this by adding () in second select :

```
mysql> select * from users where id = 1 and (select * from users where id = 2);
```

and this error showing up :

> ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

i solve this by make the select in subquery :

```
mysql> select * from users where id = 1 and (select 1 from (select * from users where id = 2)a);
```

and i got this result :

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | username | password |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | Dumb     | Dumb     |
+----+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

so why the result not are the id = 1 and id = 2 ? why just id 1 result appear in table ?

i expect this result:

```
+----+----------+------------+
| id | username | password   |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 | Dumb     | Dumb       |
|  2 | Angelina | I-kill-you |
+----+----------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

***i dont want to solve this , i need to know why using and with two select not give me the two results?**

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?, `AND` operator used for condition clause. use `UNION` instead

Comment: @arisalsaila , i know union is doing the job well , but i asked why and not giving me the 2 results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get those results with a much simpler statement:

```
select * from users where id = 1 or id = 2;
```

If you really want that format, you should be using `UNION`.

```
select * from users where id = 1 UNION select * from users where id = 2;
```

> `select * from users where id = 1 and (select 1 from (select * from users where id = 2)a);`
>   so why the result not are the id = 1 and id = 2 ? why just id 1 result appear in table ?

The query is getting the record where `id = 1` and then using your other statement as an extra condition.